# Draw icons Bgl/Blf

Tags: python, scripting

I have drawn text in a modal operator using blf, I wonder if icons, shapes or boxes could be drawn the same way using Python.
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can definitely draw them, but I don't know if it's the same way as the texts.  The addon "SpeedFlow" by Pit wazou does use custom icons as image files.

Comment: I wonder if it could be drawn by pixels rather than images, but the image method would be fine too.

Comment: That I'm not too sure of.  I myself is in the middle of researching the draw_handler for Modal operator myself.  And you are actually ahead of me.